# Could not initialize class org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jdbc

My app does not include the org.springframework.ws dependency. It seems to be a jdbc issue.

Writing a web app and practicing security. this message comes up when I try to login to a mysql database called testdatabase.

The stack trace is as follows:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/SpringSecurityTut1] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.cleanupParameters(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:713)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:737)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:787)
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUsersByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:151)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:102)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

This is my SecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    public void congigureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource);
    }


    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http            
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

This is my application-config file

```
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.springsecurityexample"/>

<context:property-placeholder 
    location="classpath*:spring/*.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdatabase"/>
    <property name="username" value="test"/>
    <property name="password" value="test123"/>           

</bean>
```

Once I click my login button the error occurs. Similar questions on stackoverflow seem to indicate a dependency problem but all dependencies seem to be in place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFound after adding spring-ws dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088165/noclassdeffound-after-adding-spring-ws-dependency)

Comment: you might have multiple versions of the jar on your classpath.

Comment: @RedDeckWins, do you mean the org.springframework.jdbc.core jar. If so how do I find the source of the duplication.

Comment: Well I typically use maven with the enforcer plugin, which detects if you have multiple versions of the same jar on your classpath.  Then to figure out where the dependency is being pulled in, I use mvn dependency:tree

Comment: Firstly, which log4j2 JARs does your web application contain?  Secondly, try restarting your web application container (Tomcat?) and log in again.  The error 'Could not initialize class XYZ' indicates that there has already been a failed attempt to load class XYZ, so have a look in the logs to see if you can find a different exception the first time Tomcat tries to load this class.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error when I included `org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M2.jar` in my project. I looked inside the jar and opened `org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils` class.I found that it is using a class `SpringProperties` which is not part of above jar.
I replaced above JAR with `spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar` and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't do anythin apart from adding this jar file to my lib directory for my project spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, alternatively we can add this to our build path. I hope this helps.