# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jdbc

Getting below exception while running spring jdbc code.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.cleanupParameters(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:72)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:702)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:684)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:716)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:726)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:794)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:813)
at com.demo.test.JdbcDemo.getEmployeeName(JdbcDemo.java:27)
at com.demo.test.App.main(App.java:38)
```

But I have attached the jar spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar in the classpath.
Working in STS and also refreshed Maven dependencies. But the issue still persist.

Comment: I dont get the project structure. How you running, how you ensured classpath is setup properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282291/could-not-initialize-class-org-springframework-jdbc-core-statementcreatorutils

Answer (score 0):

This question was already asked in Stack OverFlow. This has to do with a jar issue. There is a conflict with spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar and some other jar related to jdbc. Make sure that the versions are matching each other. Also try doing maven update on the project.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I updated maven dependency and also changed the jar version from 4.3.8.RELEASE to various other versions like 4.3.0.RELEASE, 4.3.5.RELEASE, 4.3.3.RELEASE, 4.3.7.RELEASE etc. But still same issue is coming.

Comment: If possible can you zip the project and send it to me if its just for academic purposes agoel3705@gmail.com

Comment: And I got this error while executing this code snippet: `public String getEmployeeName(int empId) {
  String sql = "SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = ?";
  return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] { empId }, String.class);
 }`